# Chat Bot not working on my web application

Tags: node.js, botframework, botconnector, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to build a chatbot using Microsoft Bot Framework. I am new to this. 
Currently I was able to built a standalone chat successfully. However, while trying to embed my chat in my application, it throws a 500 Internal Server. (PS: currently running my application in localhost)

This is all what I have done till now(I believe I may hay have missed some steps):

1. Registered the app with /api/messages and https endpoint.
2. Added the Direct Link Channel (The Web Chat was already there).
3. Embeded the Web Chat in my html with Web Chat secret key(not the tokens).
4. Then added the hello world chat bot in server.js that connects with the localhost as well. [Hello World Code](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/overview/#navtitle)
5. Finally run the code.

I could access my application from local host and also see the chat control interface shown in front end. However when I type something it throws 500 Internal Server Error.

Please let me know what I am missing out.

PS: application in MEAN stack

Comment: I have also tried changing the embed web chat with Direct Line Secret key. Still recieve the same error

Comment: Can you share your bot code so we can better help you debug the issue?